# How to generate random numbers with specific interval between every random number

Tags: java, sorting, random

I am trying to generate 8 random numbers between range say for example 1 to 100. I am generating fine but I need to generate random numbers with specific difference between all the generated random numbers and both min max range values excluded. Say in 1 to 100 I have to generate numbers as 2,12,22,32,42,52,62,72. Is there anyway I can generate random numbers like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its not random after the first number is generated. Just keep adding `10` and storing.

Comment: If you have an specific interval between them, just the first number will ever be random. The others will inherently be the first number plus `n*interval`. In your example: `2` (random), `2+(1*10) = 12`, `2+(2*10) = 22`, `2+(3*10) = 32`, `...`

Comment: @Haris can u tell me how to exclude both min and max value i.e. 1 and 100 while generating random number

Comment: @AlmightyR I missed some statements one more thing is I don't know the interval I just know the max range suppose if its 100 interval is 10, if its 1000 interval will like 100 so on.. Is there a way I can achieve it?

Comment: Can you post the code you have written so far? That would help us see where you are coming from. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also don't forget to accept an answer if it's helpful!

Comment: You're only shifting the goalpost with that. From `rand+(n*interval)` to `rand+(n/amount)`. The problem of your first number being the only random number remains. Others are at a regular distance from the first and from each-other, and can't be random by definition. If what you mean is to have a shift in the random's `min` and `max` according to the last random, all you need to do is get the orininal values, and add the value of the randoms recursively, as they get chosen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to generate a random number and then add the initial value to the output. I adapted an example from http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62 to fit your problem.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ini = 1;
        int end = 100;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            // for this particular example we must add one to ini
            // so that ini is excluded from the output
            generateRandomInt(ini + 1, end, random);
        }
    }

    private static void generateRandomInt(int ini, int end, Random random){
        int range,randomInt,randomNumber;
        range = end - ini;
    randomInt = random.nextInt(range);
        randomNumber =  randomInt + ini;    
        System.out.println("Generated : " + randomNumber);      
    }
}
```

Comment: But don't you require a fixed interval between all numbers?

Comment: @Ian Mc Yes the interval needs to fixed based on the given range, any idea on how to implement this logic to decide the range.

Comment: You can change teh interval by changing the ini and end integers from the example

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided, N=100, number of random numbers R=8, and interval V=10.  The sequence starts with F (first number, which is to be random).

Sequence is F, F+V, F+2*V, ... F+(R-1)*V

This sequence occupies space S = (R-1)*V+1 space.  In this example, range is 2 to 72, or S=71.

You also asked to exclude mix and max (1 and 100).

So the permissible **random** space left L = N - S - 2 = 27.

So F becomes a random number between 1 and 27, then add one to avoid the min value.

The sequence follows once you have F.

EDIT:  You may also randomly calculate V if that is not provided (see formula for S; V follows from knowing N and R)